# How would I resize a polygon to fit in the canvas? Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently coding a congruent triangle drawer, it looks like this: [GUI Of Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZPsD.png)
It basically works this way: You input the length of the base that is the side BC and then you input the degrees of the point ⋪B and ⋪C, and then it calculates the interception between two lines that are made from the angles( A point to draw ∆ABC ), I visually drew them so you can understand it better [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR2p5.png),

```
b = (b_x, b_y)
b_a = (b_x + math.cos(to_radian(-b_angle)) * 400, b_y + math.sin(to_radian(-b_angle)) * 400)

c = (c_x, c_y)
c_a = (c_x - math.cos(to_radian(c_angle)) * 400, c_y - math.sin(to_radian(c_angle)) * 400)
```

Now the problem is that when you input long degrees, the interception of the two lines (A point coordinates) the A point is made out of the canvas so you can't actually see the whole triangle(as you can see in the first image), so I'm here for a solution to resize the triangle(or polygon) and make it fit in the canvas, I already thought about checking if the A coordinates are greater than the canvas size, but since I'm not familiar with tkinter and python, I don't know how to resize the triangle and make it fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scale()` to resize the polygon.

Assume `canv` is the instance of `Canvas` and the `triangle` is the id of the polygon object:

```py
x1, y1, x2, y2 = canv.bbox(triangle) # get the bounding box of the triangle
w, h = x2-x1+10, y2-y1+10  # make the w and h a bit larger
canv_w, canv_h = canv.winfo_width(), canv.winfo_height() # get canvas width and height
r = min(canv_w/w, canv_h/h) # determine the scale ratio
canv.scale(triangle, 0, 0, r, r) # resize triangle
canv.config(scrollregion=canv.bbox(triangle)) # adjust the view window
```

Comment: I did this and It didn't work, I will put the code in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did this, but it doesn't draw the triangle and I can't see any changes :

```py
triangle = self.canvas.create_polygon(coords, fill="light blue", outline="black")
canvas_w, canvas_h = self.canvas.winfo_width(), self.canvas.winfo_height()
if a[0] > canvas_w or a[1] > canvas_h:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.canvas.bbox(triangle)
    w, h = x2 - x1 + 10, y2 - y1 + 10 
    scale_r = min(canvas_w / w, canvas_h / h)
    self.canvas.scale(triangle, 0, 0, scale_r, scale_r)
    self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(triangle))
```

Note: "a" is equal to the tuple of coordinates of the point "A"

```py
a = (a_x, a_y)
```

Comment: What are the values of `coords`? What do you get from `print(canvas_w, canvas_h, x1, y1, x2, y2)`?

Comment: How about if `a_x` or `a_y` is negative?

Comment: `coords` its a list of all the points, A, B and C, 

`a = (a_x, a_y)
b = (b_x, b_y)
c = (c_x, c_y)
coords = []
for i in a + b + c:
    coords.append(i)`

Comment: the print its :
1, 1, 112, 90, 189, 152

Comment: The size of canvas is 1x1 which means that you call the code just after creating the canvas.  Add `self.canvas.update()` before the code.

Comment: That's it! Thank you! I learned a lot from you!